# Can a graph reading program give us irrational numbers?

Tags: matlab

I'm thinking of a program that gives us a graph from a function and also reads the graph and then gives coordinates of a point in the graph.

But, can the program give us the coordinates in irrational numbers?

For example, the function is y=x.

Then the program marks a point where it's (sqrt(2),sqrt(2)).

Then, can the program process the graph image and the point so that it gives us the point's coordinate is (sqrt(2),sqrt(2)), not giving us an answer such as (1.414, 1.414)?